# What does it mean by " concentrations are (value) in relation to each other"?

Tags: physical-chemistry

This is not a home work help question or something like that, these days I self learn chemistry and when I was doing a model paper I came across this question. And the question itself is not difficult but I don't understand this term.

More accurately, I am not familiar with this term, 

 
that part of the question says,

> The cation Ag+(aq) and Hg2^2+ are in an aquesous solution.Their concentrations are 0.2 moldm-3 in relation to each other. Find which cation precipitates first as its iodide when a solution of NaI is added gradually to the above solution... *and there are some other sub questions,*

If you can explain to me if what it means by "Their concentrations are 0.2 moldm-3 in relation to each other", I think I can do the question easily, Thank you!

[image: and this is the answer for that question]

Comment: Post the full sentence and the context. As written, it does not mean $anything$.

Comment: I just did, thank you for pointing me out. Hope it makes sense now

Comment: Strictly one should refuse this exercise to be evaluated, in case of assignment. It is wrong.

Comment: @Alchimista this is a question from a model paper targetting Sri Lankan AL examination. ( And I attached an image of the given answer )

Answer (score 2):

> The cation Ag+(aq) and Hg2^2+ are in an aqueous solution. Their
>   concentrations are 0.2 moldm^-3 in relation to each other. Find which
>   cation precipitates first as its iodide when a solution of NaI is
>   added gradually to the above solution

It is a poorly worded question. The author means that the ratio of Ag conc. to Hg conc. is 0.2. It is implied that the concentration of silver is lower. Which ion will ppt out first, if we add NaI?

The author should have written that the relative ratio of Ag:Hg concentration is 0.2.

Comment: Hm, If it is the relative ratio, why to mention the unit just next to the value? And you must mean "the concentration of silver is lower". I agree the question is worded very poorly.

Comment: I referred the marking scheme just now and it seems to be they have used that 0.2moldm-3 concentration in both Ksp equations, I just attached that image to question. Thank you!

Comment: Sujee0_0, Ignore the question it is meaningless written and solved. Tell your teacher that there are problems with it.

Comment: yes looks like it is my only option @M.Farooq Thank you for the support!